# Move a pgf plot, after its drawn, (on a layer) behind another plot in same axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have already seen [Filling path in pgfplot and pushing into background?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48725/filling-path-in-pgfplot-and-pushing-into-background) - that doesn't help me much because it's simply about `axis on top`. I've also seen [Why does pgfplots package cause tikz layer to disappear?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77594/why-does-pgfplots-package-cause-tikz-layer-to-disappear) - I don't think I'm hitting that bug, as I'm on pgfplots 1.5.1 (and the example in the answer there works for me as is).

Anyways, this is my MWE - in it, I'd like the strokes of the `cos(x)` function to be drawn behind the strokes of the `sin(x)` - even if `cos(x)` is plotted after `sin(x)` (this is a stand-in for my eventual use case, where I'd like to calculate some intersections based on a plot, and draw them behind the plot):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarelayer{front}
\pgfdeclarelayer{back}
\pgfsetlayers{back,main,front}
% \pgfsetlayers{back,front}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{front}
      \filldraw (0.5,0.5)--(1.5,0.5)--(1.5,1.5)--(0.5,1.5)--cycle;
      \addplot[name=one,blue,mark=+,domain=1:64] {sin(deg(x))};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{back}
      \addplot[name=two,red,mark=+,domain=1:64] {cos(deg(x))};
      \filldraw [red] (0,0) --(2,0)--(2,2)--(0,2)--cycle;
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{axis}
    \filldraw [green] (0,0) --(1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It produces something like this:

[image: test_pdf]

... zoomed in `evince`:

[image: zoom_evince]

The problems here are:

- even if the `cos` is supposedly drawn in the "back" layer - its strokes (red) are still above the `sin` (blue)
- If I use `\pgfsetlayers{back,front}`, instead of `{back,main,front}` - I get a blank output; which probably means that the plots are drawn on `main` anyway (with layering controlled by order of addplot commands), and so drawing in `back` or `front` layer fails
- The `\addplot`s are shown - however, the `\filldraw`s within the `axis` environment aren't

Is it possible to use layering in this sense in a pgf plot, within an `axis` environment?

Comment: I get it right. Can you magnify you pdf and see please?

Comment: current version is 1.9. so updating will fix many things and will add improvements regardless of your issue.

Comment: Thanks @HarishKumar - added a zoomed view (click on the images, they're linked to full size).

Comment: Thanks @percusse - looks like I may as well be hitting old buggy behavior ... though, if someone remembers a workaround (short of patching/updating) from the old days, I'd certainly like to know it `:)`

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't update the package? Your MWE works as you expect for me on v1.9, as others have noted. This is likely to be closed as off-topic since that is the convention for issues resolved by package updates here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an outdated version of `pgfplots`.